# Using Haskell signature to create function through different types

Tags: function, haskell, types, signature

I'm new to Haskell and I been trying to make this function `g :: a -> b -> [(b,a)]`.

I kind of got to the type result `[(b,a)]` (not entirely) through this:
`[(length a , a)]`.

Never got to make the signature correctly especially passing from type `a` to `b`.

Almost 6 hours on this particular function unable to figure it out. Can someone help me?
Note that I'm a truly beginner so if it's possible and not asking to much please stick to the basics.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that your function is meant to do? g ab = repeat (b,a) has the required type and returns in an infinite list of a tuple consisting of the second parameter followed by the first parameter.

Comment: Pretty much can do whatever we want, the only catch that has to have the exact signature.
The thing that I don't understand is how repeat goes from a -> b -> [(b,a)].
Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: in ghci, type `:t repeat` and it tells you the type (a -> [a]) ... so it takes a type and returns a list of that type .... so we need the input to repeat to be type (b,a) and it will return a type of [(b,a)]

Comment: Well, the definition `g a b = []` satisfies the type signature. Does this help? Note - it may not satisfy the conditions of the assignment, but the type checker won't complain if you declare `g :: a -> b -> [(b,a)]`.

Comment: I probably took the signature to literal thinking that the function would needed three steps, I kind of understand now, but still a little bit confused.
Thanks for both of you.
So how could I satisfy the entire signature?

Comment: No the type signature is for allowing partially applied functions.  so you can for instance `f = g 1` which will have type `f :: b -> [(b,a)]` and then you can call `f "a"` and `f "b"`.  Search for currying for more information.

Comment: Also, this question isn't really very good ... if you don't understand type signatures then ask a specific question about what you don't understand about type signatures .... this will never be useful to anyone else.

Comment: I know it's too specific but but after 6 hours feeling a little bit frustrated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can start with a simpler type

```
g' :: a -> b -> (b,a)
```

can be read as g' takes two arguments and returns a tuple of them in reverse order.

Now, extend it to a list of tuples

```
g :: a -> b -> [(b,a)]
```

there is the trivial case `[]`, singleton case `[(b,a)]` with a single element, infinite case, or any other arbitrary number of elements in the list.  For example,

```
doublePair :: Int -> Int -> [(Int,Int)]
doublePair x y = [(y,x),(y,x)]
```

Comment: Thanks @karakfa. by the way what is the difference between `=>` and `->`, like in `g :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> bool`?

Comment: funny you ask, answered the same question today, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32974148/1435869

Comment: Great, got it! Thanks.