# How is the Floating typeclass different from Double?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

```
*User> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

I don't understand what `Floating a => a -> a` is trying to tell me.
My professor told me `sqrt` can be thought of like `sqrt :: Double -> Double`.
And it does act like that but what does `Floating a => a -> a` mean?

Thank you

Comment: Does this question solve your doubt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974091/what-does-mean-in-a-type-signature/32980202#32980202

Comment: The best professor a programmer can have is the programmer himself: http://learnyouahaskell.com, http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/ to name a few resources for becoming self-taught and to stop relying on professors.

Comment: @ErikAllik, what? I think the professor was justified in making this simplification. They didn't want to get into type classes yet, and it's impossible to do much with numbers in Haskell without using functions that happen to be class-polymorphic.

Comment: @dfeuer: well, I wasn't questioning the professor — just offering some alternatives to the uni.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A useful thing to try interactively in `ghci` is the `:info <something>` command, which can sometimes tell you helpful things.

```
> :info Floating
class Fractional a => Floating a where
  pi :: a
  exp :: a -> a
  log :: a -> a
  sqrt :: a -> a
  (**) :: a -> a -> a
  ---------------------------------------- loads more stuff
         -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

What does this mean? `Floating` is a *type class*. There is more than one type of floating point numbers. Indeed, two come as standard: `Float` and `Double`, where `Double` gives you twice the precision of `Float`. The `a` in `Floating a` stands for any type, and the big list of operations (including `sqrt`) is an interface which any instance of the class must implement. The fact that `sqrt` is in the interface for `Floating` means that it can always and only be used for instances of `Floating`. That is, to you its type is given as you say

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

The `=>` syntax signals a *constraint*, here `Floating a` to its left. The type says

> for any type `a` which is an instance of `Floating`, given an input of type `a`, the output will have type `a`

You can specialize this type by filling in `a` with any type for which the constraint `Floating a` can be satisfied, so the following are both true

```
sqrt :: Float -> Float
sqrt :: Double -> Double
```

Now, `Float` and `Double` are represented by different bit-patterns, so the computational mechanisms for taking square roots is different in each case. It's handy not to have to remember different names for the different versions used for different types. The "constraint" `Floating a` really stands for the record (or *dictionary*) of the implementations for type `a` of all the operations in the interface. What the type of `sqrt` is really saying is

> given a type `a` and a dictionary of implementations for all the `Floating` operations, I'll take an `a` and give you an `a`

and it works by extracting the relevant `sqrt` implementation from the dictionary and using it on the given input.

So the `=>` signals a function type with an invisible dictionary input just as `->` signals a function type with a visible value input. You don't (indeed, you can't) write the dictionary when you use the function: the compiler figures it out from the type. When we write

```
sqrt :: Double -> Double
```

we mean the general `sqrt` function invisibly applied to the `Floating Double` dictionary.

Comment: The fact that these functions and constants are in a class called `Floating` is rather sad, especially when square roots ate really very much simpler than, say, general exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the part to the left of `=>` as a set of constraints.

`Floating a` means: the type `a` must be an instance of the `Floating` type class. I assume you know what type classes are. If not, see [this](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) or search for "haskell type classes"

So: `Floating a => a -> a` means: given any type `a` that is an instance of the `Floating` type class, this function has type `a -> a`. Because Haskell has more than one type of floating point numbers, this "more generic" type is used. One instance of `Floating` is indeed, `Double`.

Comment: thanks. so since we do not specify what we are going to send in as input we say `a -> a` to simplify it ,since there are several types of floating point numbers (Double,Float)

Comment: @Charana true, but not enough: we don't allow *any* `a`. We only allow `a` such that `Floating a` is true, or in other words, only `a`'s that are instances of `Floating`.

Answer (score 2):

`Floating` is a type class. You can think of it as a collection of numeric types which support the following operations:

```
sqrt, exp, log, (**) 
trig functions:  sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan, pi
hyperboolic trig functions: sinh, cosh, tanh, asinh, acosh, atanh
```

If you know Java, then you can think of a typeclass like Floating as Java interface.

Examples of types which are in the `Floating` class:

- Float  (single precision floating point)
- Double
- Complex Double

`Complex Double` are complex numbers where the real and imaginary parts are represented with `Double` values.

Examples of types which are not in the `Floating` class:

- Int
- Char
- String

The signature `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` translates roughly as:

> For any type **a**, if **a** is in the **Floating** class, then **sqrt** is a function taking an **a** and returning an **a**

This means that you can write code like this:

```
root a b c = (-b + sqrt (b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
```

and you can call `root` with either `Double`, `Float` or `Complex Double` arguments (provided they are all of the same type). For example:

```
import Data.Complex

ghci> let root a b c = (-b + sqrt (b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)

ghci> root 1 0 1 :: Double
NaN           -- can't represent sqrt -1 as a Double

ghci> root 1 0 1 :: Complex Double
0.0 :+ 1.0    -- sqrt -1 as a Complex number = i
```

Note how the same expression `root 1 0 1` gave different results based on what we forced the return type to be.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this problem instead:

```
axe :: Log -> (Log, Log)
```

A function that splits wooden logs in two. Can we generalise this? Turns out we can:

```
class Splittable l where
  axe :: l -> (l,l)
```

Now axe is not specific to `Log`s, but can split anything that's soft enough.

```
instance Splittable Log where
  axe = ... -- previous definition, for logs

instance Splittable Neck where
  axe = ... -- executable version
```

For `sqrt` it's similar: this function sure makes sense for (positive) `Double`s, but it can also operate on more general types of numbers. For instance,

```
> sqrt (-1) :: Double 
    NaN    -- urgh... negative numbers don't have real roots!
> :m +Data.Complex
> sqrt (-1) :: Complex Double 
    (- 0.0) :+ 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Floating a` bit is a constraint requiring the type `a` to belong to the class of types that represent, or are viewable as, floating point numbers, that is, `a` belongs to the `Floating` class, or, `a` is an instance of `Floating`.

You can, sort of, think of type classes like interfaces — a type `a` either implements that "interface" or it doesn't; now `sqrt` simply works on any type `a` that implements `Floating`.

But don't get too carried away with this analogy — it ends almost as quickly as it begins: there are more differences between, say Java, interfaces and Haskell type classes than there are similarities, but the analogy is useful for "getting on board".

---

To sum up, `Floating a => a -> a` means: a function from values of *any* type `a` to values of that same type `a` (i.e. `a -> a`), for as long as the type `a` resembles a floating point.

Doing `:i Floating` in a GHCi REPL will, in addition to the structure of the `Floating` type class, show you a list of the types that implement it:

```
Prelude> :i Floating
class Fractional a => Floating a where
    ... LOTS OF FUNCTION DECLARATIONS ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

Constraints have a language of their own in Haskell and can be composed, so you can have `(Floating a, Floating c, Foo a, Bar [b], Baz c) => a -> [b] -> (a, c)` or some other crazy imaginary type signature.