# Relationship between Haskell's 'forall' and '=>'

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, polymorphism

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the relationship (and interactions) between Haskell's `forall` and `=>` (and for that matter the `.` that often connects them).

For example

```
λ> :t (+)
λ> :t id
```

give

```
(+) :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
id :: forall a. a -> a
```

and while I understand how these work in these specific cases, I'm not comfortable parsing the expressions (signatures?) `forall a. Num a =>` or `forall a.` themselves into something meaningful, or that I can generally understand in more complex contexts.

What do `forall a. Num a =>` and `forall a.` mean? Specifically, what is the roles played in each by `forall`, `=>` and `a`?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/32980202/828361 answer of mine may help a little.

Comment: The most confusing part is that the `forall` is very often optional; GHC will *implicitly* insert enough `forall`s in type signatures to bind all the type variables one way or another. It's only mandatory for higher-rank types and when you want a type variable to be in scope in some inner binding.

Comment: @dfeuer: What's a "higher-rank type"?

Comment: Rank 2 polymorphism is where a function takes an argument that is itself required to be polymorphic. Rank 3 polymorphism is where a function takes a function as an argument that itself requires its argument to be polymorphic.

Comment: @dfeuer: So: `(forall a. a -> a) -> ...` vs. `forall a. ((a -> a) -> ...)`: the former is mandatory, because specifies a function that must itself be polymorphic? In other words, it is required when it is to the left of the `->`, but not when it is "above" it (in the syntax tree) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @pigworker: Yes, that helps a lot, for `forall`; but I'm still not clear on how it interacts with `=>`.

Comment: There is no special interaction between `forall` and `=>`. The only interaction is the same as that between `forall` and `->`, namely that the type-level variable bound by `forall` can be used by type-level things (e.g. constraints left of `=>`) in its scope. The `=>` is a lot like `->` in that it stands for a type of functions, to which arguments get passed at run time. However, the thing left of `=>` has kind `Constraint`, not `*`, and in source Haskell, the lambdas and applications for constraints are kept invisible. A `Constraint` is a type for an invisible record.

Comment: @pigworker: So in effect `A => ...` parallels `x -> ...` in that it specifies an argument. In the former case, this argument (1) is *not* supplied visibly by the user, but invisibly by the compiler itself and (2) must be a `Constraint`. This leaves me with a few things I don't understand though: (a) What exactly is a `Constraint`? I hear "dictionary" sometimes, but that doesn't clear things up. Is it a list of functions? (b) Doesn't `forall` also behave as in  (1), so that `forall a. Num a =>` results in *two* invisible, compiler-supplied arguments?

Comment: Yes, that's right. A thing of kind `Constraint` is the 'type' of a dictionary. A type `class` declaration introduces new things of kind `Constraint` and specifies the *methods* contained in the dictionaries which will instantiate the 'constraint'. The dictionary is the invisible argument, a record of method definitions, supplied by the compiler on the basis of the types involved. E.g., if the constraint says `Eq a`, the corresponding dictionary contains the relevant definition of `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`, which is what your code will actually call when equality testing is needed.

Comment: Cool. So if I looked what was "in Core" for, say, `f :: forall a. Eq a => ...` it would have `f (some type) (some dictionary) ... `. And if my definition of `f` had `==` in it, the compiler would look up `==` in `some dictionary`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(As another perspective, without invoking the "implicit dictionary passing" implementation of type classes):

---

`forall a.` in Haskell means "for every type `a`".<sup>1</sup> It's introducing a type variable, and declaring that the rest of the type expression has to be valid *whatever* choice is made for `a`.

You usually don't see it in basic Haskell (without turning on any extensions in GHC), because it's not necessary; you just use type variables in your type signature, and GHC automatically assumes there are `forall`s introducing those variables at the start of the expression.

For example:

```
zip :: forall a. ( forall b. ( [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)] ))
zip :: forall a. forall b. [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zip :: forall a b. [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

The above are all the same; they just tell us that `zip` can be a way of zipping a list of `a` together with a list of `b` to make a list of `(a, b)` pairs, *whatever choice we feel like making for `a` and `b`*.

`forall` mainly comes into play with extensions, because then you can introduce type variables with scopes *other* than the default ones assumed by GHC if you don't explicitly write them.

---

Now, the `constraints => type` syntax can be read roughly as "these constraints imply this type", or "provided these constraints hold, you can use this type". It's used all the time, even in vanilla Haskell with no extensions, so it's important to understand what it means and how it works and not just copy and paste and hope.

The `=>` arrow allows us to state a set of constraints on the variables in the rest of the type expression; it lets us put limitations on what choices can be made to introduce the type variable. You should read it first by ignoring everything left of the `=>` arrow, and reading the the right part on its own. This gives you the "shape" of the type. The stuff to the left of the `=>` arrow tells you what kind of types you can use the rest of the type with.

An example:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

This means that `(+)` is exactly the same kind of thing as anything with a simpler type like `a -> a -> a`, *except* the `Num a =>` is telling us that we're not free to choose **any** type `a`. We can only choose a type for `a` when we know that it is a member of the `Num` type class (another slightly more precise way of saying "`a` is a member of `Num` is "the constraint `Num a` holds").

Note that GHC is still assuming that there's an implicit `forall a` to introduce the type variable `a` here, so it really looks like:

```
(+) :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
```

In which case you can read this off moderately easily as an English sentence once you know what `forall a.` and `Num a =>` means: "For every type `a`, provided `Num a` holds, plus has the type `a -> a -> a`".

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're familiar with formal logic at all, it's just an ASCII-friendly way of writing ∀a, a "universally quantified variable".

Comment: How does this map to the [hidden compiler-supplied arguments](http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/10/polymorphism-for-dummies.html) that `forall` creates? Does `=>` add another, or change the form of the one that  `forall` creates?

Comment: Those are different things, so yes there will be "extra arguments" for the `forall`ed variables and for each type class dictionary. But they're also completely different kinds of "implicit argument". A type variables introduced by `forall` is an "implicit argument" that is totally resolved at compile time, with zero presence or overhead at runtime (even without optimizations). It's also only an argument to the *type*, not to the actual function; that explanation is trying to get across that `forall a. a -> a` should be seen as an infinite family of types, parameterised by the choice of `a`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Type class dictionaries on the other hand are *genuinely* arguments at runtime; they have to be created and passed around between functions. **HOWEVER** I would strongly discourage you from trying to understand `forall` and `=>` this way. The "implicit arguments" (either at type level in GHC's intermediate output, or at value level at runtime) are the *implementation strategy* for parametric polymorphism and type class constraints; not what they *mean*. There are alternative possible implementations.

Comment: IMHO trying to explain type class constraints by talking about implicit dictionary passing is like trying to explain classes in Java by talking about vtables.

Comment: I agree; but once dictionaries (which I'd never heard of before in this context) and "what the compiler does" were unleashed, they had to be run to ground; and the process, IMV, ended up being illuminating. Though you're correct that that all covers just one possible approach to realizing the meaning of `forall` and `=>`, having one concrete example of how that meaning is made made the meaning clearer.

Answer (score 3):

As the `forall` matter appears to be settled, I'll attempt to explain the `=>` a bit. The things to the left of the `=>` are arguments, much like ones to the left of a `->`. But you don't apply these arguments manually, and they can only have specific types.

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
```

is a function that takes two arguments:

1. A `Num a` dictionary.
2. An `a`.

When you apply `f`, you just provide the `a`. GHC has to provide the `Num a`. If it's applied to a specific concrete type like `Int`, GHC knows `Num Int` and can supply it at the call site. Otherwise, it checks that `Num a` is provided by some outer context and uses that one. The great thing about Haskell's typeclass system is that it ensures that any two `Num a` dictionaries, however they are found, will be identical. So it doesn't matter where the dictionary comes from—it is sure to be the right one.

#### Further discussion

A lot of these things we're talking about aren't exactly part of Haskell so much as they're part of the way GHC interprets Haskell by translation to GHC core, AKA System FC, an extension of the very well-studied System F, AKA the Girard-Reynolds calculus. System FC is an explicitly typed polymorphic lambda calculus with algebraic datatypes, etc., but no type inference, no instance resolution, etc. After GHC checks the types in your Haskell code, it translates that code to System FC by a thoroughly mechanical process. It can do this confidently because the type checker "decorates" the code with all the information the desugarer needs to plumb all the dictionaries around. If you have a Haskell function that looks like

```
foo :: forall a . Num a => a -> a -> a
foo x y= x + y
```

then that will translate to something that looks like

```
foo :: forall a . Num a -> a -> a -> a
foo = /\ (a :: *) -> \ (d :: Num a) -> \ (x :: a) -> \ (y :: a) -> (+) @a d x y
```

The `/\` is a type lambda—it's just line a normal lambda except it takes a type variable. The `@` represents application of a type to a function that takes one. The `+` is really just a record selector. It chooses the right field from the dictionary it's passed.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what a "dictionary" is? Is that a list of functions ("methods") with certain required type signatures?

Comment: And: aren't they're *two* *two* two hidden arguments in the example : a [type for `formal`](http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/10/polymorphism-for-dummies.html), a `Constraint` (or dictionary or list of functions?) for `=>`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, yes, there is a hidden type argument. I was talking about the arguments (potentially) passed at runtime; type applications don't survive compilation. A dictionary is a record containing (potentially) dictionaries for superclasses and (potentially) each class method. An `Applicative` dictionary might look something like `data ApplicativeDict f = ApplicativeDict {functorDict :: FunctorDict t, app :: forall a b . f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b, pur :: forall a . a -> f a, ...}`

Comment: So conceptually (setting aside what actually survives), `forall` says that the function needs an argument that specifies a type, and `=>` says that a suitable collection of functions is *additionally* required? And these are not provided by the caller, but by GHC (based on context, especially what *is* provided by the caller, as conventional `->` arguments)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorus, the "conventional" arguments do constrain/guide the type checker, but they don't themselves "carry" dictionary information (except in the case of GADTs and existentials, which can). The dictionaries flow implicitly through the contexts. Simon Peyton Jones gave an excellent talk about the process at Microsoft a few years ago, and the video is online somewhere. BTW, see my edits.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it helps if we add the implied parentheses:

```
(+) :: ∀ a . ( Num a => (a -> (a -> a)) )
id :: ∀ a . ( a -> a )
```

The `∀` always goes together with a `.`. It's basically special syntax meaning “anything between `∀` and `.` are type variables that I want to introduce into the following scope”<sup>†</sup>

`=>` denotes what Idris calls an implicit function: `Num a` is a *dictionary* for the `instance Num a`, and such a dictionary is implicitly needed whenever you're adding numbers. But whether `a` is a type variable here that was previously introduced by some `∀`, or a fixed type, doesn't really matter. You could also have

```
(+) :: Num Int => Int -> Int -> Int
```

That's just superfluous, because the compiler *knows* that `Int` is a `Num` instance and hence automatically (implicitly!) chooses the right dictionary.

Really, there's no particular relationship between `∀` and `=>`, they just happen to be used often together.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually this is a *type-level lambda*. The type expression `∀ a . b` behaves analogously to the value level expression `\a -> b`.</sub>

Comment: I wouldn't call `∀ a` a type-level lambda. Haskell has `∀ a` in types, but does not have type-level lambdas e.g. `F (\t -> Maybe (t,t))` is illegal in Haskell, but allowed in Agda. `∀ a` is however a binder in types like `\a` is in terms.

Comment: @chi GHC represents `forall`s as type level lambdas in Core and GHC Haskell [will allow direct access to this fact soon](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication). What you are talking about is more general, though and is a bit different. Because of this difference (I think), GHC Core `forall` lambdas are written as uppercase lambdas.

Comment: @DavidYoung I disagree. In GHC Core, foralls are written `forall` in _types_. In _terms_, these forall-types are introduced by `\ @x -> ...` which are analogous to System F uppercase lambdas, or "type lambdas". These are term-level lambdas which bind types, to provide "terms which depend on types" as in System F. Still, there are no lambdas inside types, hence no type-level lambdas. (I do see that it's only a matter of terminology, not semantics. Still, in my limited experience a "type-level lambda" means another thing. I might be wrong on this, though :-) )

Comment: Pi is not lambda — it's pi. I think, if `F (\t -> Maybe (t,t))` would be allowed in Haskell, then it would be a type-level lambda, but in Agda it's just an ordinary term and hence plain old [value-level] lambda.

Comment: `forall` is not really the same thing as Pi in dependent type theory: it's parametric, so it behaves more like an *intersection* than a *product*. An inhabitant of a `forall a. t` type, given by some `/\a. b`, amounts to a *single* mechanism which works to deliver `t`, whatever `a` is given (relying on what they have in common). An inhabitant of a type `pi a. t` represents a bunch (like in a product) of potentially different mechanisms for computing a `t` for each possible `a`. Haskell doesn't have `pi` yet, but it's coming. Agda and Idris have `pi`, but could really do with `forall`, too.

Comment: @pigworker, but isn't `Pi (A : Set) ...` being parametric (I know, these two parametricities are different, but nevertheless) is basically the same as Haskell's `forall` (only for `Set` of course)?

Comment: Calling `=>` an "implicit function" isn't clarifying things for me. Why does that mean — "is an instance of"?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The caller has to "prove" that the chosen `a` is an instance of the class by providing its methods as hidden arguments: this is done by the compiler under the hood. E.g. `f :: forall a. Show a => ...` is handled, roughly, as if it were `f :: (a->String) -> ...`. In this way, when the code of `f` uses `show`, the compiler can simply invoke it through the implicit `a->String` argument. On calls to `f`, the compiler will add a suitable argument for the programmer, according to the available instances.

Comment: If you're going to use non-Haskell syntax in your answers (∀), then I at least suggest you explicitly state that you are and that when you say "∀" it should be read as "forall". Or just don't do it and use the Haskell syntax to answer a Haskell question :)

Comment: @ChristopherArmstrong: `∀` isn't Haskell syntax any less than `forall`, both are enabled with GHC extensions. It just needs `-XUnicodeSyntax` in addition to `-XRankNTypes`.

Comment: @chi: [I gather](http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/10/polymorphism-for-dummies.html) that under the hood, `f :: forall a . a -> a ...;  f x = ..` is something like `f @a x = ..`; but what about `f :: forall a. Show a => ...`? If that's handled roughly, as if it were `f :: (a->String) -> ...`, where did the `forall` argument go? Shouldn't there be *two* additional hidden arguments:  a type for `forall` and a `Constraint` (or dictionary or list of functions?) for `=>`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, precisely. In Core it's something like `f @a showMethod ... = ...`. Note that at runtime the `@a` argument is not really present. So, only a pointer to `showMethod :: a->String` is actually passed.

Comment: So conceptually (setting aside what'a present at runtime), `forall` says that the function needs an argument that specifies type, and `=>` says that a suitable collection of functions — *which presumably must be functions provided by some typeclass of which that type is an instance* — is *additionally* required? And these are not provided by the caller, but by GHC (based on context, especially what *is* provided by the caller, as conventional `->` arguments)?