# What exactly does => do in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've just started reading through Learn You a Haskell for Great Good.  In chapter 3, I've seen the author use => but I could not find out exactly what it does and why they use it.

I think this is the first time it was used:

```
lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String  
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"  
lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

Here is another example:

```
tell :: (Show a) => [a] -> String  
tell [] = "The list is empty"  
tell (x:[]) = "The list has one element: " ++ show x  
tell (x:y:[]) = "The list has two elements: " ++ show x ++ " and " ++ show y  
tell (x:y:_) = "This list is long. The first two elements are: " ++ show x ++ " and " ++ show y
```

Thanks.

Comment: Was answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974091/what-does-mean-in-a-type-signature/32974148#32974148

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't find that link even though I used similar wording.

Comment: @DxAlpha: Don't worry. Your question is still adding value, as the next one who looks for `=>` might find it. Duplicates aren't necessarily bad things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**:

Although not complete, if you haven't yet read about `class`es, you can see it as a constraint that there is defined a set of functions on the type `a`.

**Explanation**:

You can see it as putting constraints on a type. For instance in the case of `lucky`:

```
lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String
```

It means the function is defined *for any type `a`, as long as `a` is an `instance` of `Integral`*.

Now I don't know if you are familiar with `class`es yet (those are not the ones used in object-oriented programming), but classes more or less introduce functions on `a` that can then by used in your function definition. For instance the class `Integral` is defined as:

```
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  quot :: a -> a -> a
  rem :: a -> a -> a
  div :: a -> a -> a
  mod :: a -> a -> a
  quotRem :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  divMod :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  toInteger :: a -> Integer
```

Now this class is rather hard to understand since it uses `=>` in the signature as well. Perhaps an easier one is `Show`:

```
class Show a where
  showsPrec :: Int -> a -> ShowS
  show :: a -> String
  showList :: [a] -> ShowS
```

It means that if `a` is an instance of `Show`, that **you can use the `show` function on `a`**. Otherwise the following line:

```
tell (x:[]) = "The list has one element: " ++ show x
```

would not compile since Haskell isn't sure it can call `show` on `x`. By constraining the type `a` however, we know that we can only use `tell` on types where `a` is an instance of `Show`, and thus the `show` function is defined.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I've gotten to the classes yet.  I usually just see it through the standard OOP definition but I wish that they would use different names if it is not based on OOP.

Comment: @DxAlpha: then see it as a constraint such that you can use a set of function defined on `a`. This is not the "full" specification, but will probably suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

It constrains a parameter `a` to a certain class, in this case `Integral` and `Show`